# Getting Wikidata incremental triples

Tags: mediawiki, rdf, mediawiki-extensions, wikidata, wikimedia-dumps

I would like to know if it is possible to get the latest incremental n-triple dumps of Wikidata.

I'm using [Wikidata Toolkit](https://github.com/Wikidata/Wikidata-Toolkit) to download the latest version of the dumps and convert them automatically in n-triple files (using `RdfSerializationExample`), but I don't know how to generate the incremental versions of that dumps (specifying modified, new and deleted entities).

My idea is to maintain updated version of the information of Wikidata in a system like [OpenLink Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/). Therefore, I think it is necessary to obtain incremental versions of n-triples.

I know that there are [incremental versions of the dumps in xml version](http://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/incr/wikidatawiki/), but I don't know how to convert them to n-triples.

So, that is the best way to proceed?

Comment: Hi, have you found the answer for this ? I would love to know this too. Thanks

Comment: No, I'm sorry. In fact I'm no longer working on this.

Comment: You would have to go via various bits of Wikibase code I imagine. Wikibase itself has a script called dumpRdf.php which dumps nt or ttl files from Wikibase entities / Mediawiki revisions.
If you are poking around the code you can take a look at the RdfBuilder class, but nothing is going to work out of the box.

Comment: That is not possible a this time.